# w3c Валидация для HTML атрибутов

Tags: html5, валидация, стандарт

Согласно [стандарта](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute) HTML5 кастомные аттрибуты должны начинаться с `data-*`.
Тем не менее почти во всех даже официальных доках, к примеру для Anjular, часто приводится код типа `ng-model=""` вместо `data-ng-model=""`.

Валидаторы на странцы с атрибутом `ng-model=""` конечно же ругаются, но никаких проблем не наблюдается. Должен ли я добавлять везде `data-*` префикс? Почему вообще кастомные аттрибуты должны начинаться с этого префикса?

Comment: В случае с ангуляром - там можно писать и `ng-model` и `data-ng-model`. Парсер сам отрежет часть с дата. И, если вам нужно чтобы валидарот не ругался - можете подобавлять `data` к названиям атрибутов.

Answer (score 0):

Основным аргументом за валидацию HTML является обеспечение кроссбраузерности. Каждый браузер имеет свои механизмы парсинга, если хром может проглотить любой код, то в других уже могут быть проблемы.

Основным аргументом против валидации является то, что она слишком строгая и не соответствует тому, как на самом деле работают браузеры.

Если у Вас все работает, то можете писать код, так Вам предпочтительнее.